# Is there a difference between the concepts explained in Shandilya and Narada Bhakti Sutras

Tags: bhakti, narada-bhakti-sutra

I came across a notion that Bhakti Sutra that Shandilya Bhakti Sutra (SBS) is devoted to Nirguna Brahman and the Narada Bhakti Sutra (NBS) focuses on devotion to Saguna Brahman. Another notion is that SBS is a polemic work while the NBS focuses on Sadhana.

Can some one point out the conceptual difference between the 2 bhakti sutras (if there is any)?